# C# project doest not defined entry point for c++ dll written by myself

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dllimport, dllexport

I'm using a `c#` socket that pass it to receive data from `c++` DLL and return received result to `c#` and do other staff in `c#`.

I have a `c++` project like this:

SniReceiver.h

```
#ifdef SNIRECEIVER_EXPORTS
#define SNIRECEIVER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SNIRECEIVER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#include <WinSock2.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall receive_socket(DWORD socket);
```

SniReceiver.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SniReceiver.h"

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall receive_socket(DWORD socket)
{
    int  iResult = recv((SOCKET)socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    return iResult;
}
```

and my c# app:

```
[DllImport(@"SniReceiver.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int receive_socket(IntPtr sock);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.200.1"), 80);
    Socket sListen = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sListen.Bind(endpoint);
    sListen.Listen(10);
    Socket sClient = sListen.Accept();

    int rec= receive_socket(sClient.Handle);

    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");            
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

when calling `int rec= receive_socket(sClient.Handle);`
get error

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'receive_socket' in DLL 'SniReceiver.dll'.

Remember I've copied `SniReceiver.dll` beside my `c#` exe

[image: Picture with DependencyWalker]

Comment: Have you tried examining your DLL with a tool like Depends? C++ has a habit of applying name mangling to function names, so the actual published name may only start with what you are expecting. The other thing to check is that both projects are targeting the same number of bits (32 or 64 bit Windows).

Comment: @SteveTodd Both projects are in x86. Dependency walker didn't help me. How could I use that? I will send a picture of dll in Depends

Comment: @SteveTodd I've added Dependency walker in my edited post.

Comment: Make method public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting the function as `__stdcall` , but declaring it in C# as `CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

Change the DllImport to:

`[DllImport(@"SniReceiver.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]`.

Comment: @EyIM Thanks for the answer. I'm not professional in c++. Would you give me some reference or book to get better in c++. Any reference that is highlighted for you?

Comment: More about calling conventions: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1388/Calling-Conventions-Demystified